# Designing websites with Wordpress (that aren't blogs)

Tags: php, html, web-services, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a few questions regarding website creation using the Wordpress CMS.

- With small client projects, do developers normally create their own theme from scratch, or implement an existing one and customize it slightly?
- Is that all website creation with Wordpress is generally, assuming it's for a website that is more or less static, without a blog? Taking a theme and making the website static?

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com .

Comment: StackExchange has a [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site, too. I think this falls under "development and management best practices", which would be on-topic there.

Comment: @Catcall - please don't advise users to cross-post, just flag privately. Also this isn't a good question for either site because it's too subjective.

Comment: Doug - in future please don't cross post questions to multiple sites, flag for a mod to review and migrate your post instead. Thanks.

Comment: I did flag it. But I felt that the first comment (for programmers.stackexchange.com) called for a better, better fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I build websites with Wordpress as a CMS pretty much every day.

The process we usually take after the design stages and mock ups is using the wordpress core theme as a basis as all of the necessary tags and php functionality is already included. Then rewrite the html, write the css then write any necessary javascript.

However, very few websites are that straightforward and the majority of time we have to build custom post types to handle and display different types of content. Thankfully this is relatively straight forward in current versions of wordpress.

To answer your question, what you are suggesting is a good place to start if you have never developed or designed using wordpress. Going from a starting point that works and removing, editing, building upon that structure means that you can always undo your changes and fall back to a position that does what it needs to.

Comment: Is the Wordpress "core theme" the theme that comes by default, the TwentyEleven one?

Comment: yes or twentyTwelve depending on the version of wordpress you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Catcall, this probably falls under "development and management best practices" and is on-topic, though it could have been in wordpress.stackexchange.com. Anyhow, answering your question one by one:

1) Developers generally use pre-made themes, either free or purchased. There is a world of themes out of there. And if anything exclusive is required, they usually customize existing themes, changing stylesheets, etc... Plugins can help a bit too in customization. It takes quite a lot to build own themes, and usually only theme builders do that.

2) Yes, you can take it to be that that is all a Wordpress website is about. You can just create pages, and give links to them through tabs/menus as the theme supports. But generally sites with regular news to be added/updated utilize the blog in Wordpress except that the themes are selected such that it doesn't really look like a blog, but rather like a news site. Eg: gigaom.com (popular news site powered by Wordpress)

You can also check out sunshinefoundation.org.in (I made this, built from default theme, TwentyEleven), slumsoccer.org (I made this too)

Comment: Wow, I love the slumsoccer website. What theme is that?